# Why does this CodeLab Example in Polymer not work?

Tags: polymer

I am doing this Polymer CodeLab:

http://itshackademic.com/static/codelabs/3-polymer-build-mobile/#5

The problem is, that I dont get it to work that the note I typ in, is shown through databinding. I also downloaded the Example from GitHub and also this one doesnt work.

https://github.com/googlesamples/io2014-codelabs/tree/master/polymer-build-mobile/step5

So I'm completely cunfused. Here is my code and it is exactly the same:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-localstorage/core-localstorage.html">

<polymer-element name="codelab-app">
  <template>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <core-drawer-panel responsiveWidth="600px" id="drawerPanel">

    <core-header-panel drawer>
      <core-toolbar>Menu</core-toolbar>
    </core-header-panel>

    <core-header-panel main>
      <core-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-click="{{toggleDrawer}}"></paper-icon-button>
        <span flex>My notes</span>
          <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
          <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
          <paper-fab icon="icons:add" on-click="{{showNewNoteInput}}"></paper-fab>
        </core-toolbar>
        <div class="content">
          <paper-input id="newNoteInput" floatingLabel label="Add a new note" on-change="{{add}}" value="{{newNote}}"></paper-input>
          <template repeat="{{data}}">
            <div center horizontal layout class="item">
              <paper-checkbox checked="{{done}}" on-change="{{dataChanged}}"></paper-checkbox>
              <div flex class="card">
                <p>{{body}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </div>
    </core-header-panel>
  </core-drawer-panel>
  <core-localstorage id="storage" name="codelab-app-storage" value="{{data}}"></core-localstorage>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer('codelab-app', {
    data: [],
    toggleDrawer: function() {
      this.$.drawerPanel.togglePanel();
    },
    ready: function() {
      this.$.newNoteInput.style.display = 'none';
    },
    showNewNoteInput: function() {
      this.$.newNoteInput.style.display = 'block';
    },
    add: function() {
      if (this.newNote) {
        this.data.unshift({
          body: this.newNote,
          done: false
        });
        this.$.newNoteInput.style.display = 'none';
        this.$.newNoteInput.value = null;
      }
    },
    dataChanged: function(){
      this.$.storage.save();
    }
  });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the paper-input on-change event is not being triggered. this is why the array is still empty. If you change paper-input for regular input - see below - the functionality works, the array is updated. But it looks like a regular input. Im not 100% sure if its ignorance on our side or a bug to be reported under the paper-input repo.

```
<input is="paper-input" id="newNoteInput"
           floatingLabel
           label="Add a new note"
           on-change="{{addNew}}"
           value="{{newNote}}">
```

I have created an issue at the repo: https://github.com/Polymer/paper-input/issues/84

Issue was resolved. Run bower update and everything should work again. If you want to see the code changes. review this commit

https://github.com/Polymer/paper-input/commit/4c46adf20e0d7332ca08005fa5df3c8d0e401346